# htmlpurifier - How to escape self closing tags?

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I have noticed that when passing html string  to [htmlpurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/), it replaces all self closing tags either by **open and closing tags** or by just open **tags**

example

Before purifying

```html
<p>
  <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
    <mmultiscripts>
       <mi>y</mi>
       <mprescripts/>
       <none/>
       <mn>2</mn>
    </mmultiscripts>
   </math>
</p>
```

After purifying

```html
<p>
   <math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
     <mmultiscripts>
       <mi>y</mi>
       <mprescripts></mprescripts>
       <none>
         <mn>2</mn>
      </mmultiscripts>
    </math>
 </p>
```

As you see the `<none/>` tag was replace after purifying by `<none>` tag Which destroyed the render of the html !

What to add in my configurations file in order to escape self closing tag? Is there any shorthand from [this list](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html) can solve the problem ?

Please note that I am using htmlpurifier through [mews/purifier](https://github.com/mewebstudio/Purifier) package which is a package specific for laravel integration.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70293773/php-html-purifier-and-mathml — Looks like MathML is a no-no for HTML Purifier.

Comment: As a side note <none /> is XML, not HTML. The rendering is "not" wrong if <none /> is an empty element.

Comment: Could you please provide your configuration? Default htmlpurifier configuration removes everything except the `<p></p>` and the content `y` and `2`.

Comment: Sure I will edit the question right now.

Comment: @NoDataFound — https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parsing-main-inforeign — MathML embedded in HTML should use self-closing tag syntax as if it were standalone XML.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `Empty` rule for the `<none>` tag may point to why the closing tag disappears. HTML `Empty` tags, like `<br>`, `<hr>` and `<img>`, self-close implicitly. But you may be able to use an `Inline` element with a `Custom` rule for allowed children that's an empty regex.

Is the 'open and closing tags' scenario a problem for you? I'm not familiar enough with MathML to know whether this isn't just a cosmetic change; if the semantic behaviour of that code remains the same, I wouldn't worry about it. I don't currently know how to solve that one.